# "I shall" vs. "I will" in an e-mail to a superior

Tags: formality, auxiliary-verbs, shall-future

In an e-mail to a superior, should I write "I shall create a page", or "I will create a page"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use "I will create a page".

However, in an email, the even less formal contraction **"I'll create a page"** would be more usual and quite appropriate.

"I shall create a page" is too formal and would sound strange.

Comment: Hello, Graham. As you might have guessed, this question (or one near enough to be considered a duplicate) has been asked and answered before.